# ProcessExit - order of DLL unloads and statics

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, dll, static

Have an EXE which implicitly loads some DLL's and others explicitly (LoadLibrary). This EXE is executing its ExitProcess (1 thread in process left) and as part of that busy unloading a DLL, say A.DLL.

A.DLL (unfortunately) has a static. The atexit callback is called and this static's destructors begins to be called, leaving a trail of destructors, until a destructor decides to do some cleanup and loads a DLL to do this. This DLL performs some methods until a crash occurs due to memory access violation since a static it was about to use in this DLL is no longer present. Looking at the stack trace of this static, its destructor has been called already as part of its DLL unload.

What happened? The DLL was loaded, performed some methods, goes to use a static (in the same DLL) but this has been destructed (static only gets destructed when dll is unloaded). So is it in a half limbo state of executing methods but is also being destructed?

The EXE seems in the context of __tmainCRTStartup which implies the user created main has returned? Are DLL's unloaded while in the context of the user main or tmainCRTStartup?

Comment: DLLs are shut down in `tmainCRTStartup`, after .exe's global's destructors have finished.

Comment: Code that calls FreeLibrary() explicitly can be quite a pain, tearing down a running program is a perilous endeavor.  If you can't get help from the code owner then exit(0) can be called for.  Do note the C++11 std::quick_exit() function, solves the same kind of problem.

Comment: There is not FreeLibrary call, the runtime is unloading the dll's...

Comment: If the process is in the context of __tmainCRTStartup then I believe the process won't have started unloading DLLs yet (which happens after __tmainCRTStartup returns control to Windows).  It sounds as if the problem isn't to do with the unloading of the DLLs but rather the runtime library processing atexit callbacks (as ElektroKraut explained).  If so, using ExitProcess instead of exiting the main function should resolve the problem - provided you don't really *need* to call any of the destructors.  Of course, that depends what they're doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's this simple: Destructors of static objects are called in reverse order of their creation, this is internally done by registering atexit callbacks. The only case where this differs is if you manually unload (FreeLibrary) a DLL.

The problem you describe only shows that you have a cyclic dependency, which can easily happen with static constructors/destructors. You should be careful in what you do in destructors, especially loading a DLL at this point seems quite dangerous to me.

Comment: I agree with you, however this is legacy code. I also understand the order of destruction and atexit callbacks. What confused me is we are in the middle of executing some dll code, but its statics have been destroyed.

Comment: As I said, this can always happen with static objects depending on each other, especially since the order of the static constructors is undefined (this is also true for static objects in one DLL)...

Comment: A.DLL is executing code, it goes to use its static (inside A.DLL). This is destroyed. So the same DLL where the static lives is running code, but with its static destroyed. That confuses me.

Comment: This is how I would imagine it to happen (simplified): (1) A static constructor A is executed (2) the DLL is loaded (3) the DLL static constructor B is executed (4) you call exit (5) the DLL static destructor ~B is called (6) the static constructor ~A is called, but tries to use B -> crash!

Comment: You have a cyclic dependency that leads to re-entrancy. During the cleanup of A's statics, you execute code that calls into A on the assumption that its statics are still valid. That assumption is not valid (A's statics are being destroyed), hence your problem.